# Why this function has been disabled?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use Wordpress CMS for my website on this address: [Mohandesclub.com](http://www.mohandesclub.com/).
Today I update wp-persian plugin for my website; (A plugin for translate the web site to the Persian languages).
It upgrade successfully, but then this error appear on top of the website.

```
Warning: ini_get_all() has been disabled for security reasons in public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 1020
```

How to fix this error?!

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37680

Comment: To fix, ask your host to remove the restriction. Certain cpanel hosts allow you to edit this setting yourself. Failing that just disable warnings - the site should still work

Comment: from your `wp-config.php` file set debug to False `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`

Comment: Prabin, that is False itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a Wordpress issue that they announce the websites to Upgrade they PHP edition to the 5.6 or greater.
https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/